# How change onMouseMove handler in other handler with react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, react-component

How we can change the `handlerOnMouseMove` inside other handler (in my example `OnClick`).
I show an example below;
normally when I do this `this.handleMouseMove = undefined;` it should disable my event `onMouseMove` but unfortunately it is not working.

```js
import React from 'react' 
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import './BasicComponent.css'

class BasicComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      id: "id",
      title: "component",
      inputs: [],
      outputs: [],
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this)
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this)

  }
    render() {
        console.log("render");
        return(
          <div  className="component" 
                onMouseDown={ this.handleMouseDown } 
                onMouseUp={ this.handleMouseUp }
                onMouseMove={ this.handleMouseMove }>
            <div className="title">Title</div>
            <div className="id">ID: c_356545454</div>
            <div className="inputs">inputs</div>
            <div className="core">core</div>
            <div className="outputs">outputs</div>
            <button onClick={ this.handleClick } >Disable handler onMouseMove</button>
          </div>
        );
    }

    handleClick() {
      this.handleMouseMove = undefined; // <===== this not disable the call on handleMouseMove ??? 
      console.log("handleClick : handleMouseMove is disabled");
    }

    handleMouseDown() {
      console.log("handleMouseDown");
    }

    handleMouseUp() {
      console.log("handleMouseUp");
    }

    handleMouseMove() {
      console.log("handleMouseMove");
    }
}

export default BasicComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class BasicComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: "id",
      title: "component",
      inputs: [],
      outputs: [],
      disableMouseMove: false,
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseUp = this.handleMouseUp.bind(this);
    this.handleMouseMove = this.handleMouseMove.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    const { disableMouseMove } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        className="component"
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={disableMouseMove ? () => {} : this.handleMouseMove}
      >
        <div className="title">Title</div>
        <div className="id">ID: c_356545454</div>
        <div className="inputs">inputs</div>
        <div className="core">core</div>
        <div className="outputs">outputs</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Disable handler onMouseMove</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ disableMouseMove: true }); // <===== this not disable the call on handleMouseMove ???
    console.log("handleClick : handleMouseMove is disabled");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can createRef for the wrapper div you are tracking the "mousemove", add the "mousemove" event listener for that ref once component mounts and remove it once the button is clicked. Hint, there is no more "onMouseMove" for the wrapping div. Below I also replaced your class methods with arrow functions in order to avoid binding them.

```
export default class BasicComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      id: "id",
      title: "component",
      inputs: [],
      outputs: [],
    }
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.myRef.current.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove)
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.myRef.current.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMouseMove)
    console.log("handleClick : handleMouseMove is disabled");
  }

  handleMouseDown = () => {
    console.log("handleMouseDown");
  }

  handleMouseUp = () => {
    console.log("handleMouseUp");
  }

  handleMouseMove = () => {
    console.log("handleMouseMove");
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef} className="component"
        onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}
         >
        <div className="title">Title</div>
        <div className="id">ID: c_356545454</div>
        <div className="inputs">inputs</div>
        <div className="core">core</div>
        <div className="outputs">outputs</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick} >Disable handler 
onMouseMove
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```